# Find the sum of the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{5^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{5^k}$$

I'm wondering if this is divergent since (-1)^k is divergent as per the rules of geometric series where $abs(x) \geq 1$ then $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ diverges.

Since we know that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{5^k}=$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{1}{5^k}$$ and $(-1)^k$ is a divergent then the rest of thte series is divergent? Is that logic right?

Comment: Look up the alternating series test.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{5^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{-5})^k=\frac{1}{1--\frac{1}{5}}=\frac{5}{6}$ by geometric series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a geometric series: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{r^n}=\dfrac{1}{1-r}$$ when $|r|<1$.

Comment: With alternating signs, it's rather $\dfrac1{1+r}$.

Comment: @Bernard No it's not, it's just that $r$ is negative.

Comment: It is correct. He just have to write it as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-\dfrac15\right)^k$. In this fashion $r=-\dfrac15$.

Comment: Yet I think the formula with $\dfrac1{1+r}$ is more natural to use for beginners.

Comment: @Bernard why?  that requires remembering an extra rule while the one used above is incredibly general and covers both cases by itself.

Comment: @JMoravitz: When I was in high school, I was taught to not reinvent the wheel systematically just to avoid having to learn formulæ. It's like music: you can't play piano just being able to read  the score – you have to train, and the more you know , the more imaginative you are.

Comment: Daily vote limit reached so I cannot upvote your comment @JMoravitz, but I agree. There is no need to remember anything besides the formula for $\frac1{1-r}$. Remembering a separate formula for $\frac1{1+r}$ is just unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks guys, I see where my logic went off the rails.

Comment: @Bernard I'm not against learning more formulas, but learning "The result of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}$ and the result of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n r^n = \frac{1}{1+r}$ is unnecessary since they *are the same formula*.  That is like saying that $n^k = n\times n\times \cdots\times n$ and $(-n)^k = (-1)^k\times n\times n\times \cdots \times n$ are both necessary to learn and worthy of separate spots on a "formula sheet" when plugging in a negative value for $n$ into the first works perfectly fine as is.

Comment: Yet I learnt it (I also learnt in the last year of mid school the factorisations of $x^n-y^n$ and of $x^n+y^n$ for odd $n$'s, which are closely related to the formulæ we're speaking of, as I discovered later).